# how to sort SQL result in an existing sorting function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello I have this sorting function ine one template of CMS. I would like to add if the condition is the second one:

```
if(is_array($array)) {
foreach($array as $row) {
    if($row[photos] == 1) { 
        if($isMobile) {
            include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.content_item_photo.php');
        }

        else

         {
            include($basepath.'/templates/template.content_item_photo.php');

        }
```

I want to add the following MySQL result to show also

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT niches.name, niches.record_num FROM niches ORDER BY name ASC");
```

which is used in this template for sorting:

```
include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item_title.php');
```

Any ideas how this can be integrated inside the first code function?

So here is the code of the main index template:

```
    <?
session_start();
if(($_REQUEST[mode] == 'favorites' || $_REQUEST[mode] == 'my_uploads') && !$_SESSION[username]) {
    header("Location: /login.php");
}

include('admin/db.php');
include($basepath.'/includes/inc.seo.php');



$cacheName = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

$cacheResult = getCache($cacheName);
$cacheTotalPages = getCache("total_pages$cacheName"); 

if($cacheResult && $cacheTotalPages) {
    $array = $cacheResult;
    $total_pages = $cacheTotalPages;
}
else {
    include($basepath.'/includes/inc.index_queries.php');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $array[] = $row;
    }
    if($thispage != 'favorites' && $_GET[mode] != 'my_uploads') {
        setCache($cacheName,$array,$overall_cache_time);
        setCache("total_pages$cacheName",$total_pages,$overall_cache_time);
    }
}

$thisfile = 'index';
$webpage="index";

if($isMobile) {
    include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.overall_header.php');
}
else {
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.overall_header.php');
}

if(empty($_GET[mode]) && !$_GET[page]) { 

    include($basepath.'/templates/template.home.php');

}

if($webpage=="index" && empty($_GET[mode]) && !$_GET[page])

{}

else
{



if(is_array($array)) {
    foreach($array as $row) {
        if($row[photos] == 1) { 
            if($isMobile) {
                include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.content_item_photo.php');
            }

            else                            

             {
                include($basepath.'/templates/template.content_item_photo.php');

            }


        }
        else {
            if($isMobile) {
                include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.content_item.php');
            }
            else 

            {
                include($basepath.'/templates/template.content_item.php');
            }

        }
    }
}


else {
    echo "Sorry, no results were found.";
}
}

if($isMobile) {
    include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.overall_footer.php');
}
else {
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.overall_footer.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "first code function" ? What do you mean by "if condition is the second one..." ?

Comment: the first condition is if the visitor is from a mobile device, So I need it for the second sorting which is not for the mobile. include($basepath.'/templates/template.content_item_photo.php');

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I get your question, but we have to start somewhere...

```
<?php
if(is_array($array)) {
foreach($array as $row) {
    if($row[photos] == 1) { 
        if($isMobile) {
            include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.content_item_photo.php');
        }

        else

         {

            include($basepath.'/templates/template.content_item_photo.php');

        }
```

Next block of code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT niches.name, niches.record_num FROM niches ORDER BY name ASC");

if(is_array(result)) {
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($row[photos] == 1) { 
        if($isMobile) {
            include($basepath.'/templates/mobile.content_item_photo.php');
        }

        else

         {

            include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item_title.php');

        }
```

Comment: when I run the Script it originaly is starting to sort everyhing with this template. basepath.'/templates/template.content_item_photo.php, So the next mysql result should be listed with this template. include($basepath.'/templates/template.channel_item_title.php');

Comment: No I guess the way I explains it it not okay.   Okay The original code is checking if you are with mobile device, if not it start sorting galleries using this template: templates/template.content_item_photo.php. What I want is , to add another div layer on this page which will list the information from the database which is this one: $result = mysql_query("SELECT niches.name, niches.record_num FROM niches ORDER BY name ASC");
but using this template template.channel_item_title.php  so the result will be listing content_item_photo + _item_title.php, in the condition not mobile

Comment: It seems like you would have to modify the content_item_photo.php then ? And include the sql-stuff in that template.

Comment: what content_item_photo.php does is just the sorting algorithm of the galleries, but where they will be shown is controlled from the code inside the index page. So what I want is to put the new div with new sorting together with the sorting of the galleries, because the template.channel_item_title.php is the same as the item_photo but it is just sorting titles instead of galleries.

Comment: Where do you put the query for template.content_item_photo.php ? And how does the code look like?

Comment: in a page inside the includes directory called inc.index_queries.php

Comment: $result_count = mysql_query("SELECT content.record_num FROM content, ratings WHERE content.record_num = ratings.id AND ratings.total_votes > $minimum_votes AND content.enabled = 1 AND photos = 0 $dateIf  GROUP BY content.record_num") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: $total_results = mysql_num_rows($result_count); 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT content.*, (SELECT content_views.views FROM content_views WHERE content_views.content = content.record_num) as views FROM content, ratings WHERE content.record_num = ratings.id AND ratings.total_votes > $minimum_votes  AND content.enabled = 1 AND photos = 0  $dateIf GROUP BY content.record_num ORDER BY content.rating DESC LIMIT $from,$max_results") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: The natural way to go would be to create the new intended SQL for template.channel_item_title.php. Where is $array coming from (in the code you supplied).